# How to prevent javascript alert on exit when user clicks on submit button

Tags: php, javascript, alert

I have the following js code installed on a form page to alert the user if he attempts to leave the page in the middle of filling out a form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
  var message = 'Data you entered may not be saved';
  if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
  evt = window.event;
  }
  if (evt) {
  evt.returnValue = message;
  }
  return message;
  }
</script>
```

It works fine when user clicks on other links or tabs in an attempt to navigate away from the page. But the javascript message pops up even when the user clicks on the submit button to submit changes in the form.

How do I prevent this js message from popping up when the form is submitted?

Comment: You have to bind to `submit` event of the form and remove the `onbeforeunload` binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your form's `onsubmit`, set a flag to tell `onbeforeunload` that it can ignore this unload attempt.

For example:

```
<form ... onsubmit="window.nounloadcheck = true; return true;">
```

And in your onbeforeunload , you can do:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
  if(window.nounloadcheck == true) return; // ignore
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options.

1. You can set a global flag when you post that you check it in the beforeunload function and act accordingly.
2. You can remove the beforeunload function when you post by setting it to an empty function or a function that just doesn't prompt.

Comment: Actually, removing the `onbeforeunload` binding seems a better & simpler option.